# groupby to display time per day per person pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to filter this dataframe by id, timestamp and my third column is the time diff between entries. I can get it to display the total sum per id for all days but can't make it work to display sum per day per id.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 1
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 2
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0), # person 2
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0), # person 2
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 3
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0), # person 3
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 3
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0)  # person 3
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2], 'timestamp': timestamps}) 
df1['new'] = df1.groupby('person').timestamp.transform(pd.Series.diff).dropna()
                               
df1.groupby('person')['timestamp','new'].sum()
```

This just gives me the total, not per day. How do I combine them per day?

Comment: There's no column called `new`. What's your  expected output ?

Comment: i forgot i calculated the difference  in that column

Comment: df1['new'] = df1.groupby('person').timestamp.transform(pd.Series.diff).dropna()

Comment: Group by both `person` and `date`: `df1.groupby([df1.person, df1.timestamp.dt.date]).sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include the date part of the "timestamp" column in your groupby condition like this:

```
>>> df1.groupby(["person", df1.timestamp.dt.date])["new"].sum()
```

Also, if you prefer, you could create a new column with the date from the timestamp and then group by that column:

```
>>> df1["date"] = df1["timestamp"].dt.date
>>> df1.groupby(["person", "date"])["new"].sum()
```

Optionally, you can `.reset_index()` at the end to contain your group values in new columns.

Comment: is there a way to sort that ?

Comment: Maybe [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) is what you need

Comment: kool! how about pulling the individual results for each person if its a really big list of ppl ?

Comment: Just use some indexing like `df[df["person"] == "Name of person"]`

Comment: oh i knew that . i guess the group by is by unique . so that should do . thank you! what did you use to learn pandas so well ?

Comment: TBH just using it at work and read the top voted questions on the  [tag:pandas] tag. Great source of information.

Comment: i guess what i m trying to say is when i do sort_values() its not unique anymore. meaning each person could repeat a few times and i wanted to sort it per person results or something like that ... maybe its not possible

Comment: Then you would need to groupby again

Comment: i guess i need something like how can i get a person that has repeatedly high results in 'new'?

Comment: Just click the tag and use the filters. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas?tab=Votes) are the question sorted by score at the pandas tag